# Do GLMM account for interdependence of data points?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, modeling, dataset

I never used Generalised linear mixed models but from what I understand they can be used when the observations are correlated.

I'm interested in knowing whether I could potentially use GLMM to analyse data from economic games such as Iterated prisoner's dilemma. For example, running several games, which involve a certain number of rounds (not-fixed), I want to use players' decision in each round as data point (response variable) as well as as the continuation probability (also different in each round) as factor variable.

Would GLMM be a good approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixed-effects models are indeed used to account for the correlations within the levels of a grouping factor. An example is something along the lines of your data, namely, measurements taken on the same subject are typically expected to be correlated.

The type of model is determined by your outcome variable. If your outcome is continuous and you can assume normal error terms for it, then you can use a linear mixed-effects model. If you have a categorical outcome or a continuous outcome for which the normal distribution is not a good choice (e.g., you have a bounded continuous outcome), then you will need to go the class of GLMMs.